# Регулярное выражение для парсинга мобильного телефона

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как на JavaScript составить регулярное выражение для номера телефона, например:

```
+71234567890
```

При том, нужно, чтобы выражение выбирало только цифры после `+7`, то есть результатом поиска будет `1234567890`

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он несёт в себе просьбу автора выполнить работу за него и не имеет никакой ценности для сообщества. Пожалуйста, ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var phone = '+71234567890',
    reg = /^\+7(\d{10})$/;

console.log( phone.match(reg)[1] );
```

Comment: Попробуем радостно запустить номер из Австралии: `+61-2-1234 5678` :)

Comment: @Other, он не просил такой телефон парсить. Он сказал, цифры после `+7`, дал пример - я вывел регулярку

Comment: Автор же не может в пример внести **все** номера, поэтому и пример.

Comment: @Other, ну начнём с того, что он принял ответ. Если бы он хотел и номер вашего типа, то написал бы об этом

Comment: Да хватит Вам придираться к моей придирке! %)

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert( '+71234567890'.match(/\+7([0-9]+)$/)[1] );
```